# Issue DMing users: Cannot read property 'getMaxListeners' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Now before I begin, I would like to state that I am a beginner at coding, and not a coding expert, so please excuse if they're any mistakes in my code, as I an still learning. Any criticism is highly appreciated, as it will better my work:

So as the title mentions,  want to be able to have a user, for the sake of this example, enter in "&test" and my bot will DM the user, saying something like "Please enter a rest response", start the message collector, then when the user replies with something like "test", the collector will end, and will send the response, "test" to the given channel ID. I would like to implement this feature, as it's current purpose is to send an update for what items are with who (on a minecraft server, yes I know, but we're a pretty big group) I have just recently thought to add this in, when I figured out anyone could respond to any users command, and the collector would just stop there, thus they kept flooding the response channel with useless embeds. Here is the current code (without the attempted implementations):

```js
client.on('message', async message => {

    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(message.content.toLowerCase() === '&reserveupdate') {
        
        message.channel.send('**Please inform us on what you are doing with the reserve down below. Remember, don\'t take more than half of the current reserve:**');
        let filter = m => !m.author.bot;
        let counter = 0;
        let collector = new discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, filter);
        let destination = client.channels.cache.get('my channel id');
        collector.on('collect', (m, col) => {
            console.log("Collected message: " + m.content);
            counter++;
            if(counter === 1) {
               message.channel.send("**Thanks for updating us on the Token Reserve!**");
                collector.stop();   
            }
            if(destination) {
                if(m.content.toLowerCase() === '&stop' && (message.author.id === m.author.id)) {
                    console.log("Stopping collector.");
                    
                    collector.stop();
                }
                else {
                    let embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
                        .setTitle("**Reserve Update.**")
                        .setDescription(m.content)
                        .setTimestamp()
                        .setAuthor(m.author.tag, m.author.displayAvatarURL)
                        .setColor('#ada228')
                        .setFooter("The Unb. 9 Bot. Developed by: Alduin#0010")
                        destination.send(embed);
                        
                }
            }
        });
        collector.on('end', collected => {
            console.log("Messages collected: " + collected.size);
        }); 
    }
});
```

And here is the attempted code I had played around with, to switch it over to DMs, collect the response, and then send the users response to a specific channel ID provided:

```js
client.on('message', async message => {

    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(message.content.toLowerCase() === '&reserveupdate') {
        
        message.channel.send('**Please inform us on what you are doing with the reserve down below. Remember, don\'t take more than half of the current reserve:**');
        let filter = m => !m.author.bot;
        let counter = 0;
        let collector = new discord.MessageCollector(discord.DMChannel, m => m.author.id, filter);
        let destination = client.channels.cache.get('my channel id');
        collector.on('collect', (m, col) => {
            console.log("Collected message: " + author.content);
            counter++;
            if(counter === 1) {
               message.channel.send("**Thanks for updating us on the Reserve!**");
                collector.stop();   
            }
            if(destination) {
                if(m.content.toLowerCase() === '&stop' && (message.author.id === m.author.id)) {
                    console.log("Stopping collector.");
                    
                    collector.stop();
                }
                else {
                    let embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
                        .setTitle("**Reserve Update.**")
                        .setDescription(m.content)
                        .setTimestamp()
                        .setAuthor(m.author.tag, m.author.displayAvatarURL)
                        .setColor('#ada228')
                        .setFooter("The Unb. 9 Bot. Developed by: Alduin#0010")
                        destination.send(embed);
                        
                }
            }
        });
        collector.on('end', collected => {
            console.log("Messages collected: " + collected.size);
        }); 
    }
});
```

The bot successfully DMs the user, with the response when the command is entered, however whenever the command is executed, the Powershell Log says:

```js
"(node:4540) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getMaxListeners' of undefined
    at new MessageCollector"
```

Could anyone give me any pointers? Any changes I should make to my code? This is a feature I would love to implement, as I believe it would be beneficial for our group, and reduce the clutter and spam. Any response is deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to attach a listener to the `discord.DMChannel` class, but that's not correct.

You need to attach a listener to the *specific* dm channel you want to listen to, in this case the message author (notice how `User` implements `TextBasedChannel` https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User)

Try

```js
let collector = new discord.MessageCollector(message.author, m => m.author.id, filter);
```

Comment: that seems to have done the trick, it no longer spits out any errors into powershell when a user enters the command, and the bot dms them. However, when I try to enter a response, it doesn't send the message, for example, "thanks for updating" and doesn't send the message. I'm assuming it revolves around:

"let destination = client.channels.cache.get('726944035167797279');
        collector.on('collect', (message, col) => {
            console.log("Collected message: " + message.content);
            counter++;"

I don't think it could be an issue with the embed code tbh

Comment: Alduiin_OSU- I'd make a new question for that. Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. :)